# Linking content with CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink

Is it possible to link (href) the `content` within a `CSS` `Selector`, e.g.:

```
body:after { 
  content: '\00a9 2013 All rights reserved.';
}
```

I would like to make the `2013 All rights reserved.` a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. Please see here: [Insert a Link Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165082/insert-a-link-using-css) for some Javascript workarounds which may help.