# how to change a link depending on body ID

Tags: php, html, css

I need to change a link on the headers of a site depending on what category the page is. currently we are using php's switch/case/break to switch out the entire "a href ...etc" link depending on the category, so for example:

```
case 'red': ?>
<a href="red.html">red</a>
<?php break;
case 'blue': ?>
<a href="blue.html"></a>
```

and so on.

is there a way to do this with css and the body id? example: body id="red", and something besides php or javascript could change the link, like css' content:before or :after? i can't figure out how to apply that to inside the a tag. thanks.

Comment: Can you pls show us some code, Im not sure what u r asking? Do yu want to Change the Style or the `href`-Attribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165082/insert-a-link-using-css

Comment: sorry, edited. so what i'd like to do, if possible, would be to change the word before .html in the href of a link depending on the body id without using php or javascript.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-content/ Look under Using Attributes, but why dont you want to use PHP? If you do it with CSS you mix Content and Design wich isnt a good thing

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this:

```
$category = "red"
<a href="<?=$category;?>.html"></a>
```

If you want a CSS solution I would import a 'theme' file like:

category_red.css
category_blue.css

On the head of the page I would call the desired category:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="category_red.css">
```

Comment: hmm, that $category = "red"
<a href="<?=$category;?>.html"></a> sounds like a great alternative, thank you! if i were to use a css theme, what would i put in the theme that could change the link though?

Comment: I would custom the tags and create classes that would be used on my web site like: Theme "Red" the CSS would be a{color:red;} and so on. a class example would be .link_color{color:red;} and then <a class="link_color" href="">link</a>