# Create hyperlink using only css (non-html)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Is there a way to use css to make a hyperlink?
Example:

```
<style>
.foo {
  onclick:url(http://google.com);}
</style>

<div class="foo">
Test!
</div>
```

--

My problem is that I'm unable edit/use html, but I do have complete access to the css for a certain web form. I want to have a hyperlink in the form, but since I can't edit the html, I need an alternative...

Comment: you can't do it through css, you can do it with JavaScript.

Comment: What Matt said + some related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/165110/1063730

Comment: That's what I figured... What about another solution to the problem? How to create a hyperlink on a form for which I can't access the html at all?

Comment: Maybe if you don't have access to the HTML, you shouldn't create links?

Comment: @MattDiamant great idea! That's a perfect solution. How did you get so smart?

Comment: If it was a solution, I would have put it as an answer. I'm just commenting on your problem.