# Enable email in CSS using CSS or jQuery that is using a pseudo element instead of an element in the DOM

Tags: jquery, css

So I cannot just add a mail to :

```css
.SPA-notRight:after {
    content: 'contact us: me@email.com';
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="SPA-notRight">
<p>Something not right?</p>
```

hyperlink to this css code. IS there a way to make this go to a hyperlink or an email?

Comment: Not using CSS, no. CSS is for styling purposes, not amending the DOM or user actions

Comment: No. Pseudo elements like `after` are not part of the actual [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

Comment: so this wont work with jquery either I suppose?

Comment: jQuery could be used to achieve what you want, but not in this way

Comment: the only way i can get the email on the screen is that way.

Comment: can a class be applied to this pseudo element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a Link Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165082/insert-a-link-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS it is not possible. `after` is a pseudo element and therefore not part of the actual [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

However, since your question is tagged with jQuery as well, why not just append the email to your `div`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".SPA-notRight").append('Contact us: <a href="mailto:me@email.com">me@email.com</a>');
});
```

---

**Demo**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".SPA-notRight").append('Contact us: <a href="mailto:me@email.com">me@email.com</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="SPA-notRight">
    <p>Something not right?</p>
</div>
```